# How is right curly brace supposed to be typed in VS2017 editor?

Tags: visual-studio

I used to type '}' with the keyboard combination left Ctrl + Alt Gr + '+' key.

Now I have updated VS2017 and I cant type the curly brace...

If I go to Options->Environment->Keyboard I see that this shortcut combination is currently assigned to:
Edit.ExpandSelectionintoContainingBlock(Ctrl+Shift+Alt++ (Text Editor))

So, how is right curly brace supposed to be typed?

Italian keyboard
this is the Key:
[image]

**EDIT**

Ok, seems to be a little bug... 
I reassing the shortcut to a different key combination.

Comment: it is italian keyboard: the key has  '+' '*' ']'  (to the left of Enter key)

Comment: Microsoft is aware of the problem apparently: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289516/cannot-type-close-brace.html